# Bootloader Problems Grub Won't Load Windows 7

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, boot-repair

I sent this to boot.repair@gmail.com, still no response thought I could get a faster solution here.

I am running Windows 7 64-bit and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on separate partitions.

The message is sent is:

Boot-Repair URL:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/1365163/

Originally I was unable to access Ubuntu after a windows update (Ubuntu was installed using wubi). Rather than logging into Ubuntu from the Windows 7 Bootloader, it lead to the grub> command prompt.  No matter what I did here, it would not log me into linux.  As a result I uninstalled Ubuntu from the Add/Remove Programs application in Windows 7.  I then re-installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using a liveCD-USB.  This time however, I created a partition.  I then restarted and got the GRUB bootloader which loads Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with no problems, however when I select windows (listed as "Windows 7 (loader)"), it just refreshes the grub bootloader instead of loading Windows 7.  I then used the Windows 7 repair disk to run bootrec/fixmbr and bootrec/fixboot.  This led to no bootloader coming up when I started my computer.  Instead I got a blank black screen with a flashing white cursor.  I went on to do a bootrec/buildbcd and bootrec/scanos.  These did nothing to change the situation.  When I ran bootrec/scanos it said that no Windows 7 installations were present.  After this I decided to reinstall WIndows 7 only for this to do nothing to change the situation.  Afterwards I did a boot-repair in which I began to get the GRUB bootloader, which would load ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but still would not load Windows 7.  I also did a sudo update-grub which recognized Windows 7 as being installed, but still didn't fix the issue of loading Windows 7.  While running Ubuntu I have no problem accessing my WIndows 7 partition which is formatted as NTFS.  It shows all the files and folders reflecting that the re-install did take place, and it also shows all of my old applications and folders in the Windows.old folder.  I am completely stuck at this point and have no clue what I should do next.  Any help you can offer me will be greatly appreciate.  Thank You  --gap

Comment: Thread on ubuntuforums: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2085213

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a Windows Recovery disk this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader , until you get direct access to Windows.
2. Then run Boot-Repair to recover the GRUB menu.